# Fixed point iteration for $\sqrt[3]{a}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

So I'm given the scheme for computing $\sqrt[3]{a}$ $$x_{k+1}=px_k + \frac{qa}{x_k^2} + \frac{ra^2}{x_k^5}$$
and I have to find the p, q, and r so that this scheme is as fast as possible.

Any hints please?

I'm thinking let $g(x) = px_k + \frac{qa}{x_k^2} + \frac{ra^2}{x_k^5}$ Then
$$g'(x) = p - \frac{2qa}{x^3} - \frac{ra^2}{x^6}=0$$ Do this for $g''(x)$,$g^{(3)}(x)$ also and try to solve for something.

Comment: These are good conditions, but you can't enforce them at all $x$, only at the fixed point. And you'll also need a condition for $p,q,r$ so that the scheme has $\root{3}\of{a}$ as a fixed point.

Comment: @HansEngler So instead of $g'(x) = 0$, I should try to solve for $g'(a^{1/3})=0$? And can you tell me more about the condition for $p$,$q$, and $r$, I don't quite understand that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem corresponds to the Halley's cubic iterative scheme (1694) for solving x^3 = a starting at x=x0. This is an extension of Newton's quadratic method. Have a look to
http://www.sztaki.hu/~bozoki/oktatas/nemlinearis/SebahGourdon-Newton.pdf
This method gives the following iterative scheme
$$x_{new} = x_{old} - f[x_{old}] / f'[x_{old}] ( 1 + f[x_{old}] f''[x_{old}] / (2 (f'[x_{old}])^2) ) $$ 
Try with $f[x] = x^3 - a$. You will be able to find your terms.

Comment: Please try to use LaTeX next time.

Comment: @nbubis. I am sorry for not using LaTeX. I am almost blind and I do not "see" what is the result of what I type.